# Integration SP Query execution shows unknown error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Executed SQL query:

```
--Scheduler SP
EXEC [SQLOAM].[OAM_SP_MPS_Print_Traces_Insert] 
    @intCompanyCode = 1, 
    @chrDomain = 'ECC-WEB', 
    @dtInsertedFrom ='01-Apr-2015', 
    @dtInsertedTo ='11-Aug-2015', 
    @intUID = 169558, 
    @intCommunityCode = 1
```

This error appears on exec that query:

> Msg 8106, Level 16, State 1, Procedure OAM_SP_MPS_Print_Traces_Insert, Line 105
>   Table 'sqlmas.GEN_U_Paper_Size' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.

Code:

```
UPDATE #Temp_OAM_MPS_Print_Traces 
SET Temp_IsValid = 'N'
FROM #Temp_OAM_MPS_Print_Traces, 
     (SELECT 
          Temp_Print_Job_ID, Temp_Printer_ID, Temp_Printed_On, COUNT('x') cnt
      FROM #Temp_OAM_MPS_Print_Traces 
      GROUP BY Temp_Print_Job_ID, Temp_Printer_ID, Temp_Printed_On
      HAVING COUNT('x') > 1) a
WHERE 
    #Temp_OAM_MPS_Print_Traces.Temp_Print_Job_ID = a.Temp_Print_Job_ID
    AND #Temp_OAM_MPS_Print_Traces.Temp_Printer_ID = a.Temp_Printer_ID
    AND #Temp_OAM_MPS_Print_Traces.Temp_Printed_On = a.Temp_Printed_On

DELETE FROM #Temp_OAM_MPS_Print_Traces 
WHERE Temp_IsValid = 'N'

BEGIN TRAN

SET IDENTITY_INSERT sqlmas.GEN_U_Paper_Size ON

if exists (select top 1 'X' 
           from HPPRINT.HPACJA.dbo.T_KnownMedia
           where not exists (select top 1 'X' 
                             from sqlmas.gen_u_paper_size 
                             where UPS_PS_Code = id_KnownMedia))
begin
    INSERT INTO sqlmas.GEN_U_Paper_Size (UPS_PS_Code, UPS_Description, UPS_Short_Description, UPS_Width, UPS_Height, UPS_Remarks, UPS_ISActive, UPS_Inserted_On, UPS_Inserted_By)
    SELECT
           id_knownmedia, lab_name, lab_name, 
           qty_width, qty_height, '', 'Y', GETDATE(), 251 
    FROM
           HPPRINT.HPACJA.dbo.T_KnownMedia
    WHERE
           NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 'X' 
                       FROM sqlmas.gen_u_paper_size 
                       WHERE UPS_PS_Code = id_KnownMedia)
END         

SET IDENTITY_INSERT sqlmas.GEN_U_Paper_Size OFF
```

Comment: We need the code for `[SQLOAM].[OAM_SP_MPS_Print_Traces_Insert]`. Looks like you're turning on the `IDENTITY_INSERT` on a table with no `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: I think you should include your store procedure code.

Comment: yeas we don't have any identity column as per our need.

Comment: So do not include a `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table> ON` on your stored procedure.

Comment: i think you ppl are saying this one :
**set IDENTITY_INSERT sqlmas.GEN_U_Paper_Size ON** 
 **set IDENTITY_INSERT sqlmas.GEN_U_Paper_Size OFF**

Comment: So remove the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` statements.

Comment: Yes. Remove those lines.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a ton for the help folks @Blorgbeard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're turning ON the `IDENTITY_INSERT` property of a table with no `IDENTITY` column. Remove these lines from your code and you're good to go:

```
set IDENTITY_INSERT sqlmas.GEN_U_Paper_Size ON
set IDENTITY_INSERT sqlmas.GEN_U_Paper_Size OFF
```